# Devise routing error: "Unknown action -- The action 'create' could not be found for UsersController"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

My devise set up was working fine before, but now, for some reason, whenever I try to sign up a new user, it tries to call users#create instead of registrations#create. I think it must be a problem with my routes.rb file. I recently added a new resource, "preferences", to my application, so the routing might be wonky:

```
Indexer2::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :preferences

  get "home/index"

  resources :posts
  resources :users

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations', :invitations => 'invitations'}, :except => [:show] do
    get "/signup" => "devise/registrations#new", :as => 'user_signup'
    get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => 'user_logout'
    get '/login' => "devise/sessions#new", :as => 'user_login'
  end 

  match '/welcome' => 'pages#welcome'

  resources :preferences, :except => [:destory, :edit, :create, :new, :index, :show]  do 
    collection do
      post "make_feed_preference"
      post "change_preference"
    end
  end

  root :to => "home#index"

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UsersController` should have `create` method.
If you don't want to write your own registration logic just do inheritance from [Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb):

```
 controller UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      #....
 end
```

This will include default Devise methods.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working, and anyways, it seems that my issue is that the application wants to call users#create, but I want it to call registrations#create.

Comment: oh, check what prints `rake routes`, there is a routes for sign in? (to Registrations#new and Registrations#create)

Comment: and check what happens if you comment `resources :users` in your routes.rb, this can be conflict with `devise_for :users`

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Commenting resources :users did it!

Comment: Actually, this worked better:   resources :users, :except => [:create]